# Is it possible to get no-scope kills while using the scope?

Tags: borderlands-2

I just started playing, and with the starting Gearbox sniper rifle, I shot some people while scoped, but it seemed like those kills registered for the no-scope Sniper Kills Challenge.

I kept sniping enemies, while trying things like releasing the scope right after I fired, to see if that would do it, but no.

Is it actually possible to get "no-scope" kills, while actually scoped?

Answer (score 1):

No It's not, that is why it's called no scope. You have got to shoot without aiming, but it's way easier to take down large enemies with no scope than small or/and fast enemies, so it might be a glitch or something.

Comment: Yeah, I think I did some no-scope kills, then scoped and did some kills, plus notification lag, and everything got mixed up.

Comment: But you know there could still be a way, Google it if you want. It's useful if you can really no-scope with a scope.

Comment: late but question out of interest. Does that apply to the uniquwe Jakobs Sniper Rife "Buffalo"? This one cannot spawn with a scope